# Use HAProxy as https forward proxy and ssl termination

Tags: ssl, proxy, haproxy

I'm trying to do something like this:

- Clients send HTTP request to HAProxy.
- HAProxy does the TLS stuff to convert the request into https and forward to a server. HTTP to the client.
- The server sends https response to HAProxy, then the response is forwarded as HTTP to client.

Currently, I'm not so sure how to achieve that goal with HAProxy. I tried to create a frontend listen on a custom port and then forward to a backend server. This is my HAProxy configuration:

```
frontend manager_https
    bind *:8443
    mode tcp
    log global
    maxconn 2000
    timeout client 50000
    default_backend     https_be

backend https_be
    timeout connect         5000
    timeout server          50000
    retries                 3
    server                  rtmp-manager 127.0.0.1:12345 check-ssl verify none
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. When clients send HTTP request, HAProxy also forward the HTTP request to backend server, not HTTPS.
How can I change the configuration to make it works as expected?

Another question: Is there any ways to make the offload transparent with client using HAProxy?

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: This is apparently not about a forward proxy, but reverse proxy which is normal usage of haproxy.

Comment: @wurtel my HAProxy runs on client side. The connection between server and HAProxy is HTTPS, and between client and HAProxy is HTTP. So it should be a forward proxy, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the `ssl` directive in the definition of your backend server, like this:

```
 server                  rtmp-manager 127.0.0.1:12345 check-ssl ssl verify none
```

Note that the `check-ssl` option affects the health checks only, and if `ssl` is specified, it can be omitted, since health checks are automatically done via SSL.

HAProxy should act as a transparent reverse proxy, so clients should not recognize that the requests are in fact handled by backend servers.

Comment: That works.
About transparency, what I really want is my clients only know about the server. HAProxy acts as MITM.

Comment: If you mean the backend servers, your clients can't know about them, since the clients typically can't reach the backend servers directly (hence, a reverse proxy). If the clients can reach the servers directly (so you need haproxy for the http->https change only), you can make a fully transparent proxy using iptables and nat/mangle, but you have to set up the proper ipchains rules and routing. Here is a doc about how it can be done, but I think it's overkill in your situation: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-2.html

Comment: Just wanted to address the `forward proxy` part in the question header. HAProxy is not supposed to be a forward proxy. You should use something like burp or squid to achive interactiveness or transparency : https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/access-internet-through-proxy/7575/4